# ERROR whitelist rejection on phonegap, need plist format

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I've researched that the whitelist rejection error requires

```
<key>ExternalHosts</key>
<array>
    <string>*</string>
</array>
```

in your plist file. I'm building this app with phonegap build (not with XCode) and I need to know where in the plist file this key goes. Currently I have it as follows:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        ...
    </array>
    <key>ExternalHosts</key>
    <array>
        <string>*</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But this is still throwing the same error.

Are there any modifications I need to make to my app in tandem with this change?

Answer (score 0):

I did put that:

```
 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction</key>
        <true/>

        ...

        <key>BackupWebStorage</key>
        <string>cloud</string>
        <key>ExternalHosts</key>
        <array>
                <string>dl.dropbox.com</string>
        </array>
        <key>Plugins</key>
        <dict>`
```

into Cordova.plist file.

Comment: ...I'm not using XCode. And I already wrote this part. I need to know where it goes...

Comment: Sorry for XCode, I put that into Cordova.plist, as I mentioned before.

Comment: Yes. But I already knew that I needed to put that in the plist. I need to know where to put it. I described where I put it and that didn't work...

Comment: thats where i have mine but i'm still getting the same error :(